# "Improve this map" message displaying outside map

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I followed [this tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/use-mapbox-gl-js-with-react/) to get a basic map layout set up in React.

After completing it, the "Improve this map" message was constantly outside the map as opposed to the bottom edge: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQQb3.png)

My App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl'; // eslint-disable-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
 

function App() {
  mapboxgl.accessToken = 'token';

  const mapContainer = useRef(null);
  const map = useRef(null);
  const [lng, setLng] = useState(-6.26);
  const [lat, setLat] = useState(53.34);
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(8);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (map.current) return; // initialize map only once
    map.current = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainer.current,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12',
      center: [lng, lat],
      zoom: zoom
    });
  });
     
    useEffect(() => {
    if (!map.current) return; // wait for map to initialize
    
    map.current.on('move', () => {
      setLng(map.current.getCenter().lng.toFixed(4));
      setLat(map.current.getCenter().lat.toFixed(4));
      setZoom(map.current.getZoom().toFixed(2));
    });
    
    });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="sidebar">
      Longitude: {lng} | Latitude: {lat} | Zoom: {zoom}
      </div>
      <div ref={mapContainer} className="map-container" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}

.map-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  }
   
  .sidebar {
  background-color: rgba(35, 55, 75, 0.9);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-family: monospace;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  }
```

Any ideas?

I tried using other tutorials, other styling options, but the message is constantly outside the map.

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake, forgot to add

```js
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css'
```